# React hooks : how to watch changes in a JS class object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm quite new to React and I don't always understand when I have to use hooks and when I don't need them.

What I understand is that you can get/set a state by using

```
const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(myStateValue);
```

So. My component runs some functions based on the url prop :

```
const playlist = new PlaylistObj();

React.useEffect(() => {
  playlist.loadUrl(props.url).then(function(){
    console.log("LOADED!");
  })
}, [props.url]);
```

Inside my PlaylistObj class, I have an async function **loadUrl(url)** that

- sets the *apiLoading* property of the playlist to true
- gets content
- sets the *apiLoading* property of the playlist to false

Now, I want to use that value in my React component, so I can set its classes (i'm using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)) :

```
  <div
  className={classNames({
    'api-loading': playlist.apiLoading
  })}
  >
```

But it doesn't work; the class is not updated, even if i DO get the "LOADED!" message in the console.
It seems that the playlist object is not "watched" by React.  Maybe I should use react state here, but how ?

I tested

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = React.useState(new PlaylistObj());
React.useEffect(() => {
  //refresh playlist if its URL is updated
  playlist.loadUrl(props.playlistUrl).then(function(){
    console.log("LOADED!");
  })
}, [props.playlistUrl]);
```

And this, but it seems more and more unlogical to me, and, well, does not work.

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = React.useState(new PlaylistObj());
React.useEffect(() => {
  playlist.loadUrl(props.playlistUrl).then(function(){
    console.log("LOADED!");
    setPlaylist(playlist); //added this
  })
}, [props.playlistUrl]);
```

I just want my component be up-to-date with the playlist object. How should I handle this ?

I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close, but basically this issue is you are not *actually* updating a state reference to trigger another rerender with the correct loading value.

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = React.useState(new PlaylistObj());

React.useEffect(() => {
  playlist.loadUrl(props.playlistUrl).then(function(){
    setPlaylist(playlist); // <-- this playlist reference doesn't change
  })
}, [props.playlistUrl]);
```

I think you should introduce a second `isLoading` state to your component. When the effect is triggered whtn the URL updates, start by setting loading true, and when the Promise resolves update it back to false.

```
const [playlist] = React.useState(new PlaylistObj());
const [isloading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  playlist.loadUrl(props.playlistUrl).then(function(){
    console.log("LOADED!");
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
}, [props.playlistUrl]);
```

Use the `isLoading` state in the render

```
<div
  className={classNames({
    'api-loading': isLoading,
  })}
>
```

I also suggest using the `finally` block of a Promise chain to end the loading in the case that the Promise is rejected your UI doesn't get stuck in the loading "state".

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  playlist.loadUrl(props.playlistUrl)
    .then(function() {
      console.log("LOADED!");
    })
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
}, [props.playlistUrl]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
import React from "react";

class PlaylistAPI {
  constructor(data = []) {
    this.data = data;
    this.listeners = [];
  }
  addListener(fn) {
    this.listeners.push(fn);
  }

  removeEventListener(fn) {
    this.listeners = this.listeners.filter(prevFn => prevFn !== fn)
  }

  setPlayList(data) {
    this.data = data;

    this.notif();
  }

  loadUrl(url) {
    console.log("called loadUrl", url, this.data)
  }

  notif() {
    this.listeners.forEach(fn => fn());
  }
  
}

export default function App() {
  const API = React.useMemo(() => new PlaylistAPI(), []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    API.addListener(loadPlaylist);

    /**
     * Update your playlist and when user job has done, listerners will be called 
     */
    setTimeout(() => {
      API.setPlayList([1,2,3])
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
      API.removeEventListener(loadPlaylist);
    }
  }, [API])

  function loadPlaylist() {
    API.loadUrl("my url");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Watching an object by React Hooks</h1>
    </div>
  );
  }
```

[Demo in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-morning-xrokw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ok, so you are using memoization here.  What would be the advantage of using this rather than a React context ?  Thanks.

Comment: It does this by accepting a function that returns the value and then that function is only called when the value needs to be retrieved (which typically will only happen once each time an element in the dependencies array changes between renders).

Comment: @AliTorki does that watch for -any- change on the initialised class?

Comment: @Oddman yes but with a new approach in react. You can use useExternalSync hook in react

Comment: @AliTorki amazing, any ideas on performance implications?

Comment: @Oddman it's up to your implementation, there is no performance impact by default.